# What does "a framework with a small footprint" mean?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is meaning of small footprint in terms of programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618065/what-is-meaning-of-small-footprint-in-terms-of-programming)

*CodeIgniter is right for you if...
    You want a framework with a small footprint.*

What does that mean?

Comment: really this needed to be a question on SO?

Comment: regarding code igniter its just meaningless blubber

Answer (score 4):

It means the size of the framework, as in disk space, is small

Comment: http://www.programmingincpp.com/code-footprint.html